# Sprites are cut or a line appears when moving the camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

I have a problem that is that when I move the camera or move it away from my 2d project in unity the sprites are cut and lines appear

The error:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You could try disabling `Anti Aliasing`

Comment: Thanks, I was able to solve the problem, yes it was the antialiasing, thankyou very much